# How can I configure a local feed for nuget packages in VSCode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, nuget-package

I'm using VSCode with the [official C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) to develop a .NET Core console app on Ubuntu. I'd like to use a private nuget package in this console app. Usually one would add a local feed for nuget packages like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds) with `nuget init c:\packages \\myserver\packages`. I've tried to find some settings in the C# extension which would allow me to configure a local feed for nuget packages but did not find any. Is it possible to do the same with the VSCode + C# extension builtin support?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can create a file named "NuGet.Config" in the directory where the solution is located and do its contents as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="KetumMyGet" value="https://www.myget.org/F/ketum/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="KetumMyBaget" value="http://localhost:5000/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="TestSource" value="c:\packages" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#example-config-file)

Comment: You mean I could run an own, private nuget server e.g. with [BaGet](https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet) and point with `value` to the corresponding URL?

Comment: Yes, it says you can do this [here](https://loic-sharma.github.io/BaGet/installation/local/), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Could you add the BaGet hint in the answer. I'll try and accept the answer then.